# Merge multiple documents of different mime type into single PDF and download in IBM Content Navigator

Tags: pdf, filenet-p8, ibm-content-navigator

I have a requirement where I need to merge multiple documents in a folder as a single PDF and download it. Is it possible using built in APIs of Content navigator or do I need to use any external APIs to develop a plugin and implement this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try going through the inbuilt service of ICN to merge documents.

```
http://server:port/navigator/jaxrs/convertDocument
```

If this doesn't work (I never tried this), you can build your own service to download and merge them into single PDF using iText.